# How to properly import CSV datasets to Django models with ManyToMany / ForeignKey relationships?

Tags: django, csv, model, foreign-keys, manytomanyfield

Novice alert! I want to use **django-csv-importer 0.1.3.5** to import data to models with ManyToMany relationships.

Should make a different model for every relation or should I put everything in the same model?

Also, note that I want to allow registered users on my site to submit a form to that same model, would that still work?

Answer (score 0):

I use django import export which is easy to use and supports many file types.

It comes with admin integration. I haven't tried many too many but tried with a foreign key, it works pretty well. Yes, the user can submit the form as well.

See https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest